# How to pass NULL or nullptr to a function that receives a unique_ptr argument?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& p1)
{
    p1.get();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto a = std::unique_ptr<int>();
    a = NULL;
    
    // this works because a is a unique ptr and it has a get method
    foo(a);
    // this does not work because NULL does not has this method. But can it work tho like how we use the raw pointer?
    foo(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

So basically I want to finish some function/API that can receive both nullptr literal and unique_ptr as funtion argument. How can I do it?

Comment: How about a `void foo(std::nullptr_t)` overload?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux damn bruh, you killed it instantly

Comment: what do you exect `T` to be when you pass a `nullptr` ?

Comment: `nullptr` != `NULL`, try to avoid confusing these two terms.

Comment: `p1.get();` is noop BTW (for `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: did not know there is a type called std::nullptr_t tho! Good to know

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True, it means probably one more int type overload

Comment: @Jarod42 Sort of; it does cause a compilation error if there is no `get()` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might write overload for `std::nullptr_t`:

```
void foo(std::nullptr_t) {}
```

And SFINAE the first form to discard it for wrong type as `int` (possible type of `NULL`):

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T&& p1) -> decltype(p1.get(), void())
{
    p1.get();
}
```

but use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: This is not correct. This overload won't be picked with a `NULL` argument. It will only pick up a `nullptr` argument.

Comment: @cigien This is not a bug, it's a feature ;)

Comment: `NULL` usage should be replaced by `nullptr` :-)

Comment: @YSC Sure, but it doesn't answer the OP's question about how to handle `NULL`.

Comment: "*NULL usage should be replaced by nullptr*" Shouldn't that be part of the answer?

Comment: @cigien True, a more int type overload should solve the NULL case. Anyway, that was the right approach

Comment: @J.R.: int overload is a wrong hack, SFINAE the first overload seems better.

Answer (score 3):

If `foo` should accept a `unique_ptr` specifically, you can write:

```
template<typename ...T>
void foo(std::unique_ptr<T...>& p1)
{
    p1.get();
}
```

With regards to using a `NULL` argument, I suggest not doing that. It's a macro that may evaluate to the `int` literal `0`, or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`, and is no longer the preferred way of signaling a pointer that is not pointing at valid memory.

You should use `nullptr` instead, and then you can write an overload to match that:

```
void foo(std::nullptr_t) {}
```

If you still want to use `NULL` or otherwise match any argument that is not a specialization of `unique_ptr`, you can add an overload that matches everything else:

```
void foo(...) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9K116s).

Comment: This is overly restrictive. You can't pass a custom deleter. When accepting a standard library type you should allow all template parameters to be known.

Comment: Also this way there is no distinction between passing `NULL` and passing `nullptr`, which defeats the purpose of `nullptr`.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Edited to allow passing of custom deleter, thanks. As to the distinction between `NULL` and `nullptr` I agree, but OP is conflating them, or at least wants to deal with them identically. What would you suggest I say regarding that?

Comment: I suggest correcting their outdated usage of `NULL`, explaining why, and recommending `nullptr` with an appropriate accompanying overload to handle its receipt.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Makes sense. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: _"It's a macro that evaluates to the int literal 0"_ [Only maybe.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Oh, forgot about that. Thanks for the help :)